# How to add fields in MongoDb document which already exist?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, postman, pymongo

I'm trying to get some POST requests using Postman to MongoDb and everything works well.

Following is the code:

```
def add_npo():

add_new_npo = mongo.db.npos

name = request.json['name']   
description = request.json['description']   
category = request.json['category']  
status = request.json["status"]
npo_id = add_new_npo.insert({'name': name, 'description':
description, 'category': category,'status': status})

new_npo = add_new_npo.find_one({'_id': npo_id })
output = {'name': new_npo["name"], 'description':
new_npo["description"], 'category': new_npo["category"], 'status':
new_npo["status"]}
return jsonify({'result' : output})
```

But how can I add new fields on the document without assigning them in advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add new fields on the document by **update** operation.

For example,

```
db.col.update({your filter}, {"$set": {"newField": newFieldValue}})
```